# Is there a word equivalent to "sighting" but for hearing?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, meaning-in-context, nouns, writing

I'm trying to write a sentence like

> Nobody goes near the caves because of monster noises.

"Nobody goes near the caves because of monster sightings" doesn't work because people have not seen the monsters, but only heard them. Is there a more eloquent word for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't give this as an answer because I think these possibilities are not quite what you need. Monster sounds, monster hearings, monster noises, monster rumours - all give some of the sense of what you ask for but none seems a perfect reflection of monster sightings to me. Perhaps others will come up with better suggestions.

Comment: @Anton IMO, a totally valid and (possibly!?) helpful use of a 'comment'.

Comment: The analogue of the common transitive verbo-nominal multi word verb 'catch sight of', 'catch sound of', **is** used though much more rarely. But it's obviously neither a single orthographic word nor a noun/nominal. But as a workaround:  << Nobody goes near the caves because of the reports that earlier travellers caught sound of monstrous noises. >>? I doubt that an analogue of 'sighting' exists for an audible 'clocking'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Kind of you. Thanks. It is an interesting and challenging question in its reasonable search for a parallel.

Comment: Not a single word, but *Nobody goes near the caves because of* **earwitness testimonies** *about the monster*.

Comment: Is it necessary to use a noun (grammatically parallel to *sightings*)? Why not something like, “Nobody goes near the caves because people have heard monsters”?

Comment: Perhaps you could just say "monster encounters". It's less specific but has the benefit of also including monster "smellings". (As well as "tastings" and "touchings", just in case . . .)

Comment: Maybe *grumbling(s)* in some way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in English there is no word specifically trying to pinpoint this after some research, as even terms like 'overhearing' are not exactly perfect in this context. I would opt for a more general word similar to 'noise' because it conveys the sound.

Answers:

1 word:

> Nobody goes near the caves because of monster commotion.

> Nobody goes near the caves because of monster clamor.

Specific but not 1 word:

> Nobody goes near the caves because of earwitness disclosures of monsters.

Comment: I was surprised to find "earwitness" in the dictionary. It sounds like a made up portmanteau.

Comment: @Barmar Well, it is existent, and in this context it downs work, I guess. 'Earwitness disclosures of monsters' is really just 'leaks of information that people heard monsters'.

Comment: @Barmar Well, eyewitness is a portmanteau word and at some point somebody had to make it up.

Comment: @Casey I meant made up by this poster, rather than a word they learned from seeing or hearing it used previously.